# Automated scripts fail to replay when RDP is closed

Tags: windows, batch-file, automation, remote-desktop, rdp

I have a automated script which has few actions related to focus and key events
I scheduled my automated script in task scheduler of remote machine (Windows 2012 Server)
I connect to RDP from my machine and perform below actions
a. Minimize the RDP
b. Close the RDP by clicking on x icon
And I expect my automated scripts to be replayed in both modes

**Noticed behaviors:**
**1. When RDP is minimized:**
**Usecase 1: Pass!**
a. I made changes to regedit as mentioned under the link https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/testing-with/running/via-rdp/in-minimized-window.html
b. I connect to RDP
c. I minimize it
**Output:**
Scripts work properly with no issues

**2. Remote machine is locked/logged-off:**
**Usecase 1: Pass!**
a. I connected to RDP
b. I created a batch file for tscon facility as mentioned under link https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/testing-with/running/via-rdp/keeping-computer-unlocked.html
c. I scheduled the batch file before automation script in task scheduler
**Output:**
The batch file will close the RDP connection by itself
Then the scripts start replaying with focus and key events working properly

**Usecase 2: Fail!**
a. I connected to RDP
b. I created batch file for tscon as mentioned above and scheduled it
c. Automation script is scheduled after the execution time of tscon batch
d. I close the RDP
e. After certain time, i connect to RDP to view the results
**Output:**
All the steps related to focus/key events fail.

So how to overcome the Usecase 2.
The tscon batch file should behave same irrespective of the RDP session active or inactive?
Does closing the RDP session manually makes the machine locked or logged-off?